# The Name of Samurai-like Force

Tags: terminology

**Hi There,**
I've been suggest to [ask here because of this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/57386/the-name-of-samurai-like-force?noredirect=1#comment72026_57386)

I've been reading some article like [definition of ninja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja)

and [I've read the comparison](https://ninjasvssamurai.weebly.com/comparing.html) with some force like samurai

> for the one thing that I've know,

if Ninja means [special force that used to sneak attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_forces)

so what samurai called in term of force in modern world??

Comment: If Ninja's are secretive and dishonourable they would be closer to being shady hitmen, whilst the samurai would be special forces.

Comment: yeah,, that will be the first chapter on my anime for sure,,
if those shade boy become special force and still being ninja,
I hope we have in term samurai in better position that not called special force too.

Comment: I see why you compared ninjas to special forces because of their covert operations but I see special forces as the most elite soldiers available that is why I linked them to samurai, and because ninjas can be hired by anyone they are like mafia hitmen, but on a side note the best hitmen are usually ex special forces members, anyways good luck with the anime, sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

A samurai is effectively a knight. A warrior aristocrat. A person of high social standing, fighting proudly and openly. So the **analogue (from the technical/tactical perspective**, not social, as most modern countries are not run by their military, the way knights ran the Middle Ages in Europa or the samurai in Japan) is **either jet fighters or main battle tanks:** They are expensive and very visible, but also highly lethal if used correctly.

Comment: wow.. thanks..
but it won't work.
I hope some more balance comparison..

Comment: @AhmadAzwarAnas Well. Ninjas were never meant to fight samurai head on. Covertly sneakying SpecOps "ninjas" could inflitrate bases and sabotage aircraft or blow up bridges to prevent the tanks from moving. But if you want more relevant answers, you will need to put more information into the question: What is the setting, what do you want from your "samurai"? (I had no way to know that you wanted them to be balanced against the "ninjas")

Comment: sorry.. I didn't plot it right.. I still guessing in this moment. but thanks again for the answer.
I already give an upvote for you. it will become some limitation for my samurai later.